# How to add HTML comments to index.html when doing a build in Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js, build, environment-variables, vue-cli-4

**Update 1**: Fixed syntax issue that caused my initial build errors.

**Update 2**: Found my own solution using a Webpack plugin. See the accepted solution.

I want to add some custom HTML comments in the `public/index.html` during a build. I added something like this:

```html
<!--
My Application
Version: <%= VUE_APP_VERSION %>
Build date: <%= VUE_APP_BUILD_DATE %>
-->
```

In my `vue.config.js`, I've set `VUE_APP_VERSION` and `VUE_APP_BUILD_DATE` accordingly:

```js
let today = new Date().toLocaleDateString(undefined, {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: '2-digit',
  day: '2-digit'
})

process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require('./package.json').version
process.env.VUE_APP_BUILD_DATE = today
```

But when I actually build (`npm run build`), the comments are removed completely and everything is minimized.

How do I preserve my comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution using `HtmlWebpackPlugin` and `WebpackAutoInject` plugins in my `vue.config.js` file; ditching the `VUE_APP_*` variable use in my `index.html` as it was causing me build errors.

```sh
npm install html-webpack-plugin --save-dev
npm install webpack-auto-inject-version --save-dev
```

My new `vue.config.js`:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const WebpackAutoInject = require('webpack-auto-inject-version')

module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? process.env.VUE_APP_PUBLIC_PATH_EN
    : '/',

  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      // index.html customization
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: 'public/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
        inject: true,
        deploy: process.env.VUE_APP_DEPLOY,
        webtrends: '/webtrends/scripts/webtrends.load.js', // include webtrends script for OPS only
        minify: {
          removeComments: false
        }
      }),

      // Auto inject version
      new WebpackAutoInject({
        SILENT: true,
        // options
        components: {
          AutoIncreaseVersion: false,
          InjectAsComment: false
        },
        componentsOptions: {
          InjectByTag: {
            // https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat
            dateFormat: 'isoUtcDateTime'
          }
        }
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

Then in my `index.html` (with a custom script to include on build):

```html
<!--
My application
Version: [AIV]{version}[/AIV]
Build date: [AIV]{date}[/AIV]
-->
<% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.deploy === 'ops') { %>
    <script src="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.webtrends %>"></script>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by using "HTML-escaped interpolation" syntax.

- <%= VALUE %> for unescaped interpolation;
- <%- VALUE %> for HTML-escaped interpolation;  **this one**
- <% expression %> for JavaScript control flows.

Note the different closing tag too.

So your `index.html` becomes:

```
<!--
My Application
Version: <%- VUE_APP_VERSION %>
Build date: <%- VUE_APP_BUILD_DATE %>
-->
```

Comment: @camaluay That works for attributes in HTML tags (like `<meta property="build-date" value="<%= VUE_APP_BUILD_DATE %>">`).


But the entire comment block in `index.html` gets removed still after `npm run build`.